# React Suite <DateRangePicker> does not satisfy Lighthouse flags ARIA roles

Tags: html, datepicker, lighthouse, accessibility

I have created [DateRangePicker](https://rsuitejs.com/components/date-range-picker) with React Suite and got the following information on [Lighthouse accessibility scoring](https://web.dev/accessibility-scoring/).

```
[role]s do not have all required [aria-*] attributes
```

**Usage**

```
import { DateRangePicker } from 'rsuite';
const instance = <DateRangePicker />;
ReactDOM.render(instance);
```

[**Runnable snippet**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/question-62809862)

What required `aria-*` attributes for picker I am missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

It is missing [`aria-expanded`](https://www.digitala11y.com/aria-expanded-state/) and [`aria-owns`](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-1.1/states_and_properties#aria-owns).

### Longer Answer

Because of the fact you have `role="combobox"` there are a couple of expected `aria` attributes in order to indicate the state and relationships.

#### aria-expanded

This is required to let the user know if the combobox is currently open or closed `aria-expanded="true"` and `aria-expanded="false"` respectively.

#### aria-owns

I would also expect to see an `aria-owns` to indicate the relationship between the `<input>` (which is tricky as they actually don't seem to use an `<input>`, unless I am missing something) and the date picker modal / popup / panel / whatever you call that thing!

### Other things

In the examples they give nothing is keyboard accessible. You cannot open the datepicker with <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>space</kbd> etc.

The whole date picker widget should be controllable with the keyboard, <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>left</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd> etc. etc. but it is not.

Maybe I am missing something but my immediate reaction is that this is not accessible at all and you would be better finding another component, just because it "passes" an automated test does not always mean it is fit for purpose, try it with a screen reader and see if you can use it.

Comment: Hi @Graham Ritchie, Thank you for your great help. The annoying message is missing through added `aria-expanded` and `aria-owns`. However, I still got `Elements with an ARIA [role] that require children to contain a specific [role] are missing some or all of those required children.`
How to bypass it? `<DateRangePicker aria-expanded='false' aria-owns='datepicker_modal' role='combobox'/>`

Comment: what is the outputted HTML, the `aria-expanded` and `aria-owns` need adding to the `<a role="combobox" ` element (it must exist on the item with the `role="combobox"`. I would guess adding it where you added it is adding it to the containing `<div class="rs-picker"` and so it is in the wrong place. You will probably have to extend (or edit) the library in order to achieve this. As I said, it isn't very accessible (I mean, Im not even sure that `role="combobox"` is the best `role` as it is designed for selects)! If you copy the outputted HTML into a jsfiddle / codepen I can have a look for you

Comment: Hi @Graham Ritchie, I added the code snippet to my post and this is what I've come up with: https://hennge-ui-mockup.vercel.app/

Comment: If I change `<DateRangePicker />` to `<DateRangePicker aria-expanded='false'/>` the error no longer shows in Axe (I can't run PSI accessibility checker as it reloads the page but it uses Axe "under the hood"). This does not fix the problems at all, as I said this datepicker is just awful for accessibility, but it does get rid of the error (you still need to implement the change of state to `aria-expanded="true"` when opened). Also the popup needs an ID so we can use `aria-owns`. Sadly there is just too much wrong with this datepicker to explain in a Stack Overflow answer. It needs rewriting!